# c3.js categories being removed on page refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor, c3.js

I have a meteor app where I am using `c3.js` for my charts, in particular [this Meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/perak/c3). The chart is a simple bar chart, which takes its values from a mongodb collection

My template looks like this

```
<template name="myBarchart">
    <div id="my-barchart">
        {{> c3 myChartData}}
    </div>
</template>
```

The helper that this template calls looks like this

```
Template.myBarchart.helpers({
    "myChartData": function() {


        Meteor.call('getChartData', function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                Session.set('chartData', result);
            }
        });
        var data = Session.get('chartData')[0];

        return {
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', data.valueOne, data.valueTwo, data.valueThree]
                ],
                type: 'bar',
                colors: {
                    data1: '#B2DFDB'
                },
                names: {
                    data1: 'Simple Chart'
                }
            },
            bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 0.5
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: ['2015', '2016', '2017']
                },
                y: {
                    label: {
                        text: 'Total',
                        position: 'outer-middle'
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Now, that chart draws correctly with each of the data points categorized correctly

[image]

but if I refresh the page, the category values are replaced with the defaults

[image]

Comment: Don't use Session then, write your data to database, Session is lost on refresh

Comment: or add your code to `onCreated/onRendered` it should call again the meteor method and set the template data or session data, Not really sure why the helper is failing in here but usually you do stuff like this one `onCreated`

Comment: Actually, @Sindis while Session is technically lost on refresh, if I refresh then the helper is called again and the Session variable is set, so that's not the problem

Comment: You should create helper that is waiting for Session to get set, and as @Mark said you should call for data on those events